# Outlook opens twice when trying to open using iFrame in IE9?

Tags: jsp, iframe, cross-browser, mailto

In my JSP, I have a hyperlink. `Onclick` of it, I need to open a mailTo outlook window. In IE9, I had an issue "Internet Cannot display Webpage" when I directly gave `href='mailTo:test@email.com` while opening the outlook window. For which I made a fix like below:

### JSP code:

```
<iframe id="<portlet:namespace />emailiframe" src="" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<a href="javascript:<portlet:namespace />feedbackEmail('test@email.com');">
<c:out value="sendFeedback" /></a>
```

### Script Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function <portlet:namespace />feedbackEmail(mailID)
{
  var iframe = document.getElementById("<portlet:namespace />emailiframe");
  iframe.setAttribute("src", "mailto:"+mailID);
}
```

This fix solved the issue happened in IE9. Instead, it introduced an issue where in IE9 COMP ON, outlook window opens twice and IE8, script error comes when outlook window opens.

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved after i changed my script code 
from this

```
iframe.setAttribute("src", "mailto:"+mailID);
```

To

```
document.getElementById('emailiframe').src = "mailto:"+mailID;
```